# bash script does not display $strings in echo statements

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I am taking a Linux course and we are covering bash scripting. The following script should print the echo statements with the string value but it doesn't.

```
#/bin/bash

echo "Enter the first string"
read str1
echo "Enter the second string"
read str2
echo $str1
echo $str2
myLen1=${#str1}
myLen2=${#str2}

if [ ! -z $str1 ]; then
    echo Length of the first string is: $myLen1
else 
    echo Please enter a value for ${str1} with more than 0 characters
fi

if [ ! -z $str2 ]; then
    echo Length of the second string is: $myLen2
else 
    echo Please enter a value for $str2 with more than 0 characters
fi
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
echo Please enter a value for ${str2} with more than 0 characters

echo Please enter a value for "$str2" with more than 0 characters

echo "Please enter a value for $str2 with more than 0 characters"

echo "Please enter a value for ${str2} with more than 0 characters"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The string has 0 characters. What, exactly, are you expecting to see when you print it?

Comment: @EtanReisner That makes sense. Obviously, nothing would print. My apologies. Instead, I just appended them to say `echo "Entry 1: ..."` and 'echo "Entry 2: ..."`

Comment: add `set -vx` to enable the shell debug/trace feature. Then  you can see each line of code before it is executed  and then the line preceded with `+`, and all variable substitutions in place. Then you can understand what is happening with your code. BTW, the `set -v` part actually processes "blocks" of code, so it will print out a giant while or for loop, and then only `+` lines that are actually executed. It can be confusing about what line is actually being executed. Add `export PS3='$LINENO >'` to see the line Number of code being executed. Good luck.

Comment: I don't know how you're executing your script, and it might still work the way you're running it, but for the first line of your script, make sure your shebang line is `#!/bin/bash`.  Looks like you forgot the exclamation point.

Comment: Use double quotes around strings and the argument list to `echo` most of the time.  There are times when that's not appropriate, but none of those somewhat esoteric cases occur in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you are in a Linux course covering bash. As such, I will share some general observations that I hope will help you generally:

**Testing and Debugging**
Start your bash script `bash -x ./script.sh` or add in your script `set -x` to see debug output.

**Syntax**
As @drewyupdrew pointed out as well, you need to specify the shell you are using at the top of the script like: `#!/bin/bash` (you are missing the **!**).

You are using the `-z` comparison operator in `[ ! -z $str2 ]`. The `-z` operator compares if the string is null, that is, has zero length. You are negating the comparison with the `!`.

A more concise way to perform this same action would be to use the `-n` comparison operator. The `-n` operator tests if a string is not null.

Additionally, it is important that variables in the test brackets, that is single `[ ]`s, must be quoted. Using an unquoted string with `! -z`, or even just the unquoted string alone within test brackets normally works, however, this is an unsafe practice.

So taking the above notes into account, along with a few other edits, I come up with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the first string"
read str1
echo "Enter the second string"
read str2

echo "This is the first string: ${str1}"
echo "This is the second string: ${str2}"

myLen1=${#str1}
myLen2=${#str2}

if [ -n "$str1" ]; then
    echo "Length of the first string is: ${myLen1}"
else 
    echo "Please enter a value for the first string with more than 0 characters"
fi

if [ -n "$str2" ]; then
    echo "Length of the second string is: ${myLen2}"
else 
    echo "Please enter a value for the second string with more than 0 characters"
fi
```

Does that help?

Comment: Mark Mitchel Yes that helped very much. The course I am taking is on edx.org, and the results or answers to a lab showed single brackets and the `! -z $str1`. I guess I did not notice the `#/bin/bash' issue because I was executing the script as `bash script.sh`. Thank you for your insight because it worked much better.

Answer (score 0):

In the part of the script where you are trying to print the input out you have just asserted that the input contains no characters. As such when the variable expands it expands to the empty string and you see no contents.